# How can i connect to Oracle 11 using PHP 7?

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, configuration, instantclient

The problem is, i have an application that the client demands it runs under Oracle DB.

I already have Client 11c installed, as well as Oracle Database.

My PHP was built using the following configuration:

```
"--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-snap-build\deps_aux\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared"
```

So i copied the instant client to this folder, and put it in the system path as well.

Still i'm getting:

```
PS C:\php> php -m
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried: ./ext\pdo_oci (The specified module could not be found.), ./ext\php_pdo_oci.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

When trying to run php -m with display_startup_errors = on

I've tried download other PHP Binaries and looked up on every possible corner of the internet.

Can anyone help me solve this?

P.S. PDO is a must.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php

Comment: @saiibitta As CLEARLY stated on the question, PDO is a must.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your oracle client libraries are the same 32-bit or 64-bit architecture as PHP.  Make sure whichever Oracle client libraries you want to use are first in PATH.  If you use Instant Client you need to have the correct VS Redistributable, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html or http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html